# Setting up ListView settings for selectable item, but highlighting does not work

Tags: android, listview

I made a super simple ListView but the highlighting function doesn't work, I don't know why.

I tried to change from listSelector to background.
I tried it with state_pressed and state_focused.
I tried to move the background drawable in a separated file.

No warnings are shown, the onItemClicklistener works fine, but no color, dosen't matter which state.

## ListView

```xml
<ListView
  android:id="@+id/theListView"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
  android:listSelector="@drawable/listview"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:focusable="true"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
</ListView>
```

## ListSelector: listview

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
            </solid>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item  android:state_selected="false">
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
            </solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

## MainActivity

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] ninja={"1","2","3","4"};
        ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ninja);
        ListView theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.theListView);
        theListView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        theListView.setAdapter(theAdapter);
        
        theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                view.setSelected(true);
                view.setActivated(true);
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick() returned: " + adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
            }
        }) ;
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

list_item_notselected.xml (in drawable directory)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#2f2f2f" />
</shape>
```

list_item_selected.xml (in drawable directory)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="#d23534" />

</shape>
```

list_item_style.xml (in drawable directory)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_selected" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_selected" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_notselected" />
</selector>
```

list_item.xml (in layout directory)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_style"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/item_img"
       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you tell me what your code is about?
It doesn't seems like my simply generated ListView, it looks more like a customized ListView.